# ANOVA test for Stocks

Tags: statistics, data-science, stock, anova

I did a psych degree years ago and I remember we used to use either ANOVA or a Covariance Matrix after an experimental questionnaire to reduce the number of overlapping questions to analyse the results.

Can I do the same here for an ETF to reduce the number of stocks to observe?
Perhaps a One-way ANOVA of ETF against its constituents?